Can a proper class be a member of a set?
There exists a definition in NBG stating that a class can be considered a set if it belongs to another class, and it is considered a proper class if it does not belong to any class. I see that this definition put forth by NBG is a restriction placed on the proper class to make it unmanageable, whether using union, intersection, power relations, or otherwise. It is merely an attempt to patch together non-contradictory formal expressions that could have been avoided by using ZFC alone.
Is there anything forcing us to adopt this definition, given that, starting from sets whose existence doesn't cause contradictions, we might eventually obtain proper classes whose existence does lead to contradiction, with previous sets being members of them? As demonstrated in Cantor's paradox, which proved that the set of all sets is not a set. What prevents us once again from obtaining new sets whose existence is logically acceptable, based on these controversial entities known as proper classes, and these proper classes become members of them?
In other words, can there be a set $A$ where $(\ldots \in x \in \ldots \in A)$
, where $x$ is a proper class, and the points represent a series of memberships that may be finite or infinite?

No; see Class: "the notion of "proper class", e.g., as entities that are not members of another entity."

@MauroALLEGRANZA When the concept of the proper class was first formulated, we did so because of the existence of sets that led to logical contradictions. Why didn't we settle for this definition and instead opted to add that a proper class should not belong to another entity? Is there any evidence or proof for us formulating this definition?

If a class belongs to another class we have the Russell's paradox again applied to classes instead of sets...

A class is a formula with a free variable. A class may be included in another (via implication), but not contained.

@MauroALLEGRANZA  I see that this definition put forth by NBG is a restriction placed on the proper class to make it unmanageable, whether using union, intersection, power relations, or otherwise. It is merely an attempt to patch together non-contradictory formal expressions that could have been avoided by using ZFC alone

Cantor insisted on the freedom in mathematics (though he did not apply such a principle uniformly), so you can certainly develop any logical theory you like, including the possibility you mentioned of proper classes being elements of sets.  But such an approach would be incompatible with ZFC since in ZFC by definition an element of a set is itself a set.

@MikhailKatz I agree with you that if a proper class belongs to a set, then by applying the axiom of extensionality in ZFC, the set without the proper class belonging to it would be equal to the set with the proper class in it. This is a contradiction, because I believe the new model should also include the axiom of extensionality, which states that two sets are equal if they have the same members

@MikhailKatz But what if, for example, we say that the proper class  x  belongs to the set A in the following way$ ((\ldots \in x \in \ldots \in A))$, where the dots represent an infinite membership chain? In that case, I do not understand how the incompatibility you mentioned would arise.

@BezinaTaki, that's an interesting idea, but this also cannot occur in ZFC.  Indeed, the axiom of well-foundedness rules out an infinite descending chain of the kind you mentioned.  If the chain is finite, then all the intermediate steps are sets by transitivity.  Though in axiomatic nonstandard analysis you do have a kind of infinite descending chain of inclusions, but that's another story :-)

@MikhailKatz The axiom of foundation  prevents us having an infinite descending membership sequence, meaning that any membership chain must have a beginning. However, it does not prevent us from having an infinite ascending sequence where $( x_0 \in x_1 \in x_2 \in \cdots \in x_n \in \cdots \in A )$, where$ ( x_0 )$ is a set, $( x_n )$ is a proper class, and after the proper class $ ( x_n )$, there can be an infinite set of ascending chains before reaching $( A )$, and $( A )$ is a set. Could you please clarify if there is any contradiction with ZFC that I may have overlooked in this example?

@BezinaTaki: What do you mean by "$( x_0 \in x_1 \in x_2 \in \cdots \in x_n \in \cdots \in A )$"? That notation does not have any obvious meaning.

@EricWofsey Here is a similarity between set $A$ and the set of natural numbers, $(\omega)$, where the membership chain in the set of natural numbers is as follows:
$[ x_0 \in x_1 \in x_2 \in \cdots \in x_n \in \cdots \in \omega ]$

@EricWofsey where $( x_0 = 0 ), ( x_1 = 1 ), ..., ( x_n = n )$. However, for $(\omega)$, we are certain that there is no number $k$  such that $( x_k = \omega )$, otherwise the set of natural numbers would not be infinite.
The same applies to $A$, with the difference being that we are discussing it without knowing how it is constructed or the number of membership chains it contains, or whether it is infinite or not.

A set is grounded if and only if all its members are grounded, in which case its rank is the smallest ordinal strictly greater than the ranks of all its members. If a set had a proper class as a member, this proper class would not be grounded (the members of each stage of the construction of the Von Neumann Universe are all grounded sets; if all the members of the proper class are sets of bounded rank then the class would in fact be a set by a subset axiom. If not then you can’t really say the proper class is grounded) and so neither would the set, contradicting foundations.

Basically, this doesn’t work because any set with a proper class as a member couldn’t be grounded, because either all the “infinite chains of memberships” you describe are indexed by bounded ordinals in which case the proper class is in fact a set or one is not indexed by an ordinal/the chains are indexed by unbounded ordinals in which case the big set isn’t grounded.

@Lukrau, when you write $\ldots \in A$ you are assuming an infinite descending chain.  As you point out, these are ruled out by foundation.

@Lukrau Since you are talking about the rank of a set, the rank of any proper class will certainly be greater than the rank of the largest set by one. However, the matter will differ here because the axiom of infinity ensures the existence of finite sets with infinite rank. This leads us to conclude that at some stage, at infinity, the rank of a set will be similar to the rank of a proper class.

@MikhailKatz but we can construct the following infinite membership chain with the set of natural numbers $(\omega)$ as follows: $[ (0 \in 1 \in 2 \in \cdots \in n \in \cdots \in \omega ) ]$, knowing that the existence of the set of natural numbers $(\omega)$ does not contradict the axiom of foundation.

OK but that's not called an "infinite descending chain".  An infinite descending chain would be $\omega \supset x_1 \supset x_2 \supset x_2 \supset \cdots$.

@BezinaTaki I don’t understand what you mean by “the rank of a set will be similar to the rank of a proper class”. My point is not just that proper classes must have infinite rank, but rather that they can’t have any ordinal rank because by definition anything with a rank $\alpha$ is a subset of something we know to be a set, $V_{\alpha}$. So if a set has a proper class as its member, because the proper class can’t have a rank, neither can the set.

@MikhailKatz I think we agree, I don’t see where I assumed the existence of an “infinite descending chain” except to say that one couldn’t exist.

@Lukrau, I agree, I am not sure what we are arguing about exactly :-)  Let me give you an example of a situation where such a chain is possible.  In axiomatic nonstandard analysis, the integers are $\mathbb N$ as usual, but there are two types of integers: standard and nonstandard.  All standard ones precede all nonstandard ones.  The collection $\omega$  of all standard integers is not a set but can be viewed as a class.  Then you have the chain of command $1\in2\in3\cdots\in\omega$ and $\omega$ is included in $\mathbb N$.

@Lukrau I understand your point regarding the von Neumann hierarchy of sets, and it is convincing if we adhere to the NBG model. As I mentioned in the comments above, it doesn't bring anything new because it doesn't allow us to deal with proper classes to produce new entities from them, making the proper class V(set of all set )the ultimate end. What if there were a new model that is flexible in dealing with proper classes, where V has its own rank unlike in the previous model? Would we then at some stage be able to have a proper class as a member of a set or not?
